# Making use of ENUM in CONSTRAINT

Tags: postgresql, constraint, postgis, enum

I am creating a PostGIS database in which a lot of schemas should have the same constraints. Meaning in the future, similar tables should have the same limitations of values entered.

My constraint would be this

```
ALTER TABLE "Test project"."rainbow table"   -- the table I want to change
ADD CONSTRAINT values_constraint [the name of the constraint]
CHECK  (colors IN ('red', 'green', 'blue'))  -- limiting 3 values in colors
```

So I thought I will do this making use of enums, which I can define and alter (by re-creating after dropping if something changes) for the whole database.

HOWEVER, I am struggling to call the enum values in the constraint defintion, which should be a check I believe

```
ALTER TABLE "Test project"."rainbow table"  -- the table I want to change
ADD CONSTRAINT values_constraint [the name of the constraint]
   CHECK  (colors IN (/*HOW TO REFERENCE THE ENUM ARRAY HERE?*/))
```

Comment: Please clarify the question by adding the `CREATE TYPE` statement and the `CREATE TABLE` statement (in particular, we need to know the type of `colors, since the plural sounds suspicious).

Comment: It is unclear to me whether you want to limit to the values defined in the `ENUM` (in which case you don't need a further constraint) or to specific values from that enum.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @Laurenz: I want to update/alter existing tables.

Comment: Thanks @BigSmoke We have a number of tables with the same values (limited to a number of possibilities). Let's say we have 15 tables each with a column rainbow. At a later stage, we might need to add value "pink" as a possible value allowed in rainbow. 

So I thought instead of going through all tables and edit constraints there (adding pink), we can have an ENUM list with all possible values for "rainbow"

Then I want to alter the table by a statement which checks all allowed colroes in the ENUM

Comment: I notice that you replied, but didn't answer my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use an [`ENUM` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html) for a column, you don't need an additional `CHECK` constraint to ensure that the values in that column are part of the `ENUM` definition.

```sql
create type "Test project"."rainbow color" as enum (
  'red'
  ,'purple'
  ,'blue'
  -- etc.
);

create table "Test project"."rainbow table" (
  color "Test project"."rainbow color"
);
```

With the above, you would be able to insert a record with the color `'purple'` in your `"rainbow table"`:

```sql
insert into "Test project"."rainbow table" values ('purple');
```

```
INSERT 0 1
```

But trying to insert a `color` that is not part of the `"rainbow color"` `ENUM` is forbidden:

```sql
insert into "Test project"."rainbow table" values ('green');
```

```
ERROR:  "Test project"."rainbow table" is not an enum
```

Adding new colors is easy:

```sql
alter type "Test project"."rainbow color" add value 'green' after 'blue';
```

Now, we *can* insert a record with `color = 'green'`:

```sql
insert into "Test project"."rainbow table" values ('green');
```

```
INSERT 0 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this elaborative answer! I mis-understood indeed the use of ENUM in the tablecolumn